# Generating dynamic Inputfields

Tags: dynamic

I want to create a bunch of input fields, four in this case, one for each element of the list "x", but since `Dynamic` has `HoldFirst` it is not evaluated. Is there any way to get around this, except for declaring it by hand, or messing with strings, I played a bit with `Evaluate , and`RelaseHold`, but without success.

```
DynamicModule[{x = Table[0, {4}]},
 Column[{
   Row[Table[
     InputField[Dynamic[x[[i]]], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny],
     {i, 1, 4}]],
   Norm[x]}
  ]
 ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

And easy and often seen way of doing this is using With:

```
 DynamicModule[{x = Table[i, {i, 4}]},
 Column[{Row[Table[
   With[{i = i}, 
       InputField[Dynamic[x[[i]]], Number, FieldSize -> Tiny]
   ], 
 {i, 1, 4}]], Dynamic@Norm[x]}]]
```

You could also write it out with `i=m` and switching symbols if you think `i=i` looks confusing.

[This page in the section "Nesting Dynamic"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) is a good read about a situation in which this trick is also used. However there it is used to avoid unwanted dynamic updates. 
Also found in the documentation with interactive examples "tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality"

**Updated with an explanation**

I've been giving out this answer a couple of times now, and I think it might be worth adding a little bit of information about what really is the problem in these situations.

The thing is that `Dynamic` has the attribute `HoldFirst`

```
Attributes[Dynamic]
```

> {HoldFirst, Protected, ReadProtected}

This means the first argument given to it is held in place, consider for example what happens when we run a `Table` over `Hold`:

```
 Table[Hold[i],{i,3}]
```

> {Hold[i], Hold[i], Hold[i]}

Because `i` is held, it doesn't change at each iteration. What we need to do to fix this is to make sure that i is evaluated before it is put into `Hold` so it ends up holding the value and not the symbol, for example by passing the value into a function

```
Table[Hold[#] &@i, {i, 3}]
```

> {Hold[1], Hold[2], Hold[3]}

Or as is typically done by using `With`

```
Table[With[{i = i}, Hold[i]], {i, 3}]
```

> {Hold[1], Hold[2], Hold[3]}

What happens is that when With[{i=i},code] is evaluated by table, the iterator symbol takes on its value, and we actually have for example for the first iteration `With[{i=1},code]` so rather then Hold holding i, it gets the value. The same trick is employed to get the value rather then the symbol into the `Dynamic`.

Comment: +1 for _"if you think i=i looks confusing"_