# help with dynamic input

Tags: dynamic, inputfield

I'm trying to build a pop up window with i lines. Each line would read:

Number of neurons in layer 1:
Number of neurons in layer 2:
etc until layer i

The user would enter a numeric value on each line. That value would be recorded as `d[1],d[2],...,d[i]`.

The solution I've come up with results in Mathematica assigning the input from any line to d[i] (for example if there are 5 lines, it assign inputs from line 1, 2..5 all to `d[5]`). I understand why it's happening. I just can't think of how I'm suppose to achieve what I want.

Here's my code:

```
a = Table[
  List[StringJoin[{"Number of neurons in layer ", ToString[i], ":"}], 
   InputField[Dynamic[d[i]], Number]], {i, 3}]; 
AppendTo[a, {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}];
CreateDialog[Grid[a, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left], Modal -> True];
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You need to change the first argument (`List[...]`) in `Table` to `With[{i=i},List[...]]`. Please check [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9958/125) to a related question.

Answer (score 3):

Simple fix. Put `With[{i=i}]` to get the indexing in the dynamic right:

```
a = Table[List[
StringJoin[{"Number of neurons in layer ", ToString[i], ":"}],
With[{i = i}, InputField[Dynamic[d[i]], Number]]], {i, 3}];
AppendTo[a, {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}];

CreateDialog[Grid[a, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left], Modal -> True];
```

On a sidenote, When I paste your code into Mathematica the `i` in `InputField[Dynamic[d[i]], Number]` turns red. If you highlight such a red character and go to the menu "help/why the coloring" it actually tells you that the order of evaluation conflicts.

I have added some more details on why this problem occurs, and why the solution works to a previous related question: [Generating dynamic Inputfields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/generating-dynamic-inputfields/9958#9958)