# How to compare the InputField values in For loop dynamically

Tags: dynamic

I am using a `For` loop for printing five `InputFields`. The loop gets its values from the variable tx. I want to compare the values dynamically with 10 and print the result. But, the comparison is going out of loop, why?

```
tx = {4, 1, 6, 7, 8};
Reap[For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
    Sow[ {InputField[tx[[i]]],Dynamic[If[(tx[[i]] < 10), "right", "wrong"]]}]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be fixed by using With on the index. Also you missed a `Dynamic` in the inputfield:

```
 tx = {4, 1, 6, 7, 8};

 yourLoop=Reap[For[i = 1, i <= 5, i++,
    With[{i = i}, 
       Sow[{
          InputField[Dynamic[tx[[i]]]],
          Dynamic[If[(tx[[i]] < 10), "right", "wrong"]]
       }]
    ]
 ]];

 yourLoop[[2, 1]] // Grid //Panel
```

[image: Output Illustration]

There's some more details about the `With[{i=i}]` solution in my answer to the question [Generating dynamic Inputfields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9957/generating-dynamic-inputfields/9958#9958)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know now how to automate the `InputField` using an index. But why not simply write them down? There are only 5 of them?

Here is an example using 2 InputFields

```
tx = {1, 2};
Grid[{
  {InputField[Dynamic[tx[[1]]], Number, ContinuousAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[If[tx[[1]] < 10, "right", "wrong", "huh?"]]},

  {InputField[Dynamic[tx[[2]]], Number, ContinuousAction -> True], 
   Dynamic[If[tx[[2]] < 10, "right", "wrong", "huh?"]]}

  }, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

If I find a way to use a `Table` or such, will update, but it did not work when I tried it.