# How can I name and manipulate several Input Fields?

Tags: code-review, inputfield

I am completely new to mathematica--and have a very basic knowledge of programming. I would really, very much appreciate it if someone could explain to me how to refer to values entered into specific input fields when making calculations. I thought I could just name each input field something like a1 and a2 and then just use them to calculate values. Is my approach wrong? Here is what I have so far-- I am able to make a chart of blank input squares. 
(My ultimate goal is to use particle charges and 1-dimensional distances in order to automatically calculate the energy between each particle)

```
a = {} 
Panel[
 Grid[
  MapThread[Prepend,
   {
    Prepend[
    Table[
      InputField[a,
      FieldSize -> {w, h}], {h, {1, 1}}, {w, {4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
         4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4}}],
   Table["a"*i, {i, 20}]]
   ,
    {"", "Chg", "Pos"}}
  ]   ]
]

values = Table[i*j, {i, 20}, {j, 20}];
label = Table["a"*i, {i, 20}];
labelwithvalues = Prepend[values, label ];
label2 = {"", label}
labelwithvaluesfinal =
  MapThread[
   Prepend, {labelwithvalues, {"", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6",
      "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a13", "a14", "a15", 
     "a16", "a17", "a18", "a19", "a20"}}];
```

Comment: Esther, `>` is for quotes. There is a button next to the quote button that is for code (code is indented by four spaces). Using code formatting we don't have to use `<br>`, just so you know in the future.

Comment: I might also add that programmatically generating input fields is pretty hard if you want them to work, and not a beginner's problem I would say. If you write the code for the input fields manually it would be much easier. `InputField[Dynamic[a[1,1]]` for example works. Now any code you write into that field will be put into `a[1,1]`, thanks to `Dynamic`.

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to do this is to work with lists or arrays rather than try and create symbols. Here is a list version.

```
chg = ConstantArray[Null, 5];
pos = ConstantArray[Null, 5];

Grid[{
  Join[{"Chg"}, 
   Table[With[{i = i}, 
     InputField[Dynamic[chg[[i]]], FieldSize -> 4]], {i, 
     Length[chg]}]],
  Join[{"Pos"}, 
   Table[With[{i = i}, 
     InputField[Dynamic[pos[[i]]], FieldSize -> 4]], {i, Length[pos]}]]
  }
 ]
```

[image]

You then enter values in the inout fields and use them for calculations. Without knowing what you are trying to do I can only provide a toy example:

[image]

Comment: +1. Do you have an explanation for the purpose of `With[{i=i},...`?

Comment: `Dynamic` is `HoldFirst`. So you need to use `With` to inject `i` into the expression.

Comment: BTW I think this is probably a duplicate

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I hadn't seen that trick before. You are right, I was later able to find an answer about this trick [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9958/731) that can also be considered a duplicate of this post.

Answer (score 2):

This mess will get you something close to what you'd like, I'll explain the details below:

```
symbols = {"a1", "a2", "a3"};
Grid[Prepend[Transpose@
Prepend[Map[{InputField[ToExpression["Dynamic[" <> # <> "$Chg]"],String,FieldSize->{4,1}], 
    InputField[ToExpression["Dynamic[" <> # <> "$Pos]"], String,FieldSize -> {4, 1}]} &, symbols], {"Chg", "Pos"}], 
Prepend[symbols, ""]]]
```

[image]

**Details:**

`InputField` can be restricted to only format its content as a string (which you could think of as simply hiding string characters if you wish) with the second argument `String` - and can made to dynamically update a variable as follows:

```
InputField[Dynamic[myVar],String]
```

As wisely pointed out by Pickett in the comments above, programmatically generating these is not a beginners problem - you need to account for the evaluation order of Mathematica. In this case I've achieved that by `StringJoin` with the infix notation `<>` and then `ToExpression` the resultant `String`

```
Map[InputField[ToExpression["Dynamic[" <> # <> "$suffix]"], String] &, {"var1", "var2"}]
```